# Code Coverage with Manual Tests Win10 store app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

Ideally I'd like to just turn on recording of code usage, run the app for awhile, close it and then get a report.

Anyone know how to do this with VS2015 on store apps?  Any issues with .net native / optimized code?

This is xaml/c#

Answer (score 0):

If you have written unit tests...

> Visual Studio > Test Explorer > Run... > Analyze code coverage for all tests.

Note:

> Not sure if this would work for store apps or not. But I think it would give code coverage results based on the unit tests. You may have to write more unit tests for proper coverage.

On Enterprise edition, you may see code colored to show code-coverage!

Comment: Doesn't look like that's even an option.  I have unit tests but really would rather see code coverage from manual tests.